# Pytorch: join tensor and dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pytorch

Using Pytorch.
Got the following tensor:

```
(tensor([[-0.0030, -7.6063, -7.6334, -7.7098, -8.3540]], device='cuda:0'),
 tensor([[ 14,  85,  45,  82,  15]], device='cuda:0'))
```

Need to join it with the following dictionary:

```
{'14': 'a',
 '100': 'b',
 '45': 'c',
 '33': 'd',
 '15': 'e'}
```

In order to get the following results:
'a','c','e'

Answer (score 1):

dictionary = {int(key):dictionary[key] for key in dictionary}
np.vectorize(cat_to_name.get)(best_5)